# VBA Lotus Notes mail ExpiryTime

Tags: vba, email, lotus-notes

I Have a Excel VBA script that read Data from a sheet and automatically make a Lotus Notes Email. The script works fine but now i like to add a ExpiryTime or ExpiryDate to the Email but i dont find the field for that.

I Hobe u can help me with that.

```
        Set Maildb = Session.GETDATABASE(Mailserver, Mailkonto)
     If Maildb.IsOpen = True Then
          'Fertig zum mailen!
     Else
         Maildb.OPENMAIL
     End If

     'Ein neues Maildokument erstellen
    Set MailDoc = Maildb.CREATEDOCUMENT
    MailDoc.Form = "Memo"
    'Mail Empfänger, CC, BCC, übergeben.
    Set SendItem = MailDoc.APPENDITEMVALUE("SendTo", "")
    Set NCopyItem = MailDoc.APPENDITEMVALUE("CopyTo", "")
    Set BlindCopyToItem = MailDoc.APPENDITEMVALUE("BlindCopyTo", "")

    MailDoc.sendto = strEmpfaenger
    MailDoc.CopyTo = strcc
    MailDoc.BlindCopyTo = strbcc


'Dim exDate As New NotesDateTime (" ")
'Dim Expiretime
'Expiretime = DateAdd("h", 8, NowTime)

'Set ExpiryTime = MailDoc.APPENDITEMVALUE("Expiration", "")
'MailDoc.ExpiryTime = Today + 1095
'MailDoc.ExpiryTime = DateAdd("m", 5, Now)
'MailDoc.ExpiryTime = Now + DateSerial(0, 0, 2)
'MailDoc.ExpiryTime = Expiretime


    'Betreff Texte Übergeben,
    MailDoc.Subject = strBetreff
    'Mail Text übergeben.
    Set rtitem = MailDoc.CREATERICHTEXTITEM("Body")
    'MailDoc.body = strText
    'Anhang einfügen.
    Call rtitem.EMBEDOBJECT(1454, "", strFilename)
    MailDoc.SAVEMESSAGEONSEND = SaveIt

    'Mail Body Text mit Signatur.
    Signature = Maildb.GetProfileDocument("CalendarProfile").GetItemValue("Signature")(0)
    MailDoc.Body = strText & Signature
    'Mail erstellen
    Dim workspace As Object
    Set workspace = CreateObject("Notes.NOTESUIWORKSPACE")

    Dim notesUIDoc As Object
    Set notesUIDoc = workspace.EDITDOCUMENT(True, MailDoc)

'notesUIDoc.ExpiryTime = DateAdd("m", 5, Now)
'notesUIDoc.ExpiryTime = Now + DateSerial(0, 0, 2)
'notesUIDoc.ExpiryTime = Expiretime


    'Body Text löschen wegen doppelten Signatur Problem
    Call notesUIDoc.GOTOFIELD("Body")
    Call notesUIDoc.FieldClear("Body")
    Call notesUIDoc.FieldClear("Footer")
    'Body Text + Signatur einfügen
    Call notesUIDoc.FieldAppendText("Body", MailDoc.Body)
    Call notesUIDoc.EDITDOCUMENT(True, MailDoc).GOTOFIELD("Body")

    MsgBox ("Die Mail wurde erstellt")

        'Aufräumen
    Set Maildb = Nothing
    Set MailDoc = Nothing
    Set Session = Nothing
    Set EmbedObj = Nothing
'######################################################################################
End Function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name of the field is `ExpireDate`.

This code line sets the ExpireDate to e.g. 10 days in the future:

```
MailDoc.ExpireDate = Session.Evaluate("@Adjust(@Now; 0; 0; 10; 0; 0; 0)")
```

Comment: Thx 
But it dident add ExpireDate in the mail

Comment: Sorry it has enter a expiredate but ist was only visible in the sendet mail. But it add only the now Date as ExpireDate.

Comment: The field is invisible in notesUIDoc but if you save the doc then you can look at fields in properties dialog box. What does it show for a date there?

Comment: What date do you see if you open in UI mail the dialog box "Zustelloptionen... / Erweitert / Ablaufdatum"?

Comment: In UI mail the dialog box "Zustelloptionen... / Erweitert / Ablaufdatum"?  => Heute

Comment: And also in the Excel VBA Debug for Date = Session.Evaluate("@Adjust(@Now; 0; 0; 10; 0; 0; 0)") ist the date of today

Comment: Thx for the Help it was a Porblem with the Date in Vba. Now it wokrs great

Comment: Great, I am glad you got it to work. I was just looking for code alternatives... :-)

Answer (score 0):

With

```
MailDoc.ExpireDate = exDate 'Date from Excel
```

ist work very well.  It dident show the expireDate by creating the mail but that isent a problem.

**The problem is that the ExpirdeDate dident show in the receiving mail**.

In the Lotus Notes Mail Overview the Mail is marked as expire and has also the rigth expirdeDate (In Eigenschaften-> ... ->ExpirdeDate. But when the mail will by open the expireDate doenst show in the Mail properties. Like
Diese Email läuft ab ....

I hope u can help me a second time ;-)